# TypeError : Object (...) is not a function react native stack navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I make an app with react native. I install all packages required to use stack navigation. But when I opened my project with the expo on the web. I got this error you see this in the image.

```
// In App.js in a new project
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please Help I trying to solve this for two days please help me I got this error every time. Error Screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4bA2.jpg)

Comment: Can you give me which versions are u using for react-native , navigation ?

Comment: I use react 0.65.1 Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, it worked for me:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack"
```

Comment: I try this But i got  a new error Which is TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Answer (score 1):

Use `import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';` instead of `import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';`

Try this code:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I use react 0.65.1 and i do some changes that you suggest to me But i got Same error.